# php/mysql routine to help me extract all dates strings stored in a column as text dd/mm/yyyy into another fresh column with mysql date datatype

Tags: str-to-date

i am new here and i need help with writing a php/mysql routine to help me extract all dates strings stored in a column as text in this format dd/mm/yyyy into another fresh column with mysql date datatype in the format yyyy-mm-dd.

i have tried to query through the table using a date range and it seems not to work, so i have resolve to change th already store dates into the proper mysql format to enable me query with date easily.

indeed i am most greatful of any assistance i get.

thanks

Handyx

Comment: Post some more info, i.e. some of your table structure and data, and you'll get some accurate answers. Is there only a single date in the current date field or are there strings of multiple dates in a single column that you need to target? @handyx

Comment: ok, i will past the query. do you mean the same format for the dates as they are in the table presently? thanks for you response

Comment: sprintf("SELECT * FROM violation v left join violation_class vc on v.v_class=vc.id left join violation_type vt on v.v_type=vt.id left join declarant d on d.id=v.declearant left join importers imp on imp.id=v.importer 
WHERE (DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE('v.date_inpected','%%d/%%m/%%Y'), '%%Y-%%m-%%d') between %s and %s) and importer = %s ORDER BY date_inpected ASC",
GetSQLValueString($colname_rs_violation, "int"),
GetSQLValueString($colname2_rs_violation, "int"),
GetSQLValueString($colname3_rs_violation, "int"));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you probably shouldn't be doing what your doing, convert the date on the go. Nevertheless here's the SQL query to do what you want to do

```
USE `DATABASE`;
UPDATE `TABLE_NAME` SET `TABLE_NAME.NEW_COLUMN` = DATE_FORMAT(
STR_TO_DATE(`TABLE_NAME.OLD_COLUMN`,'%d/%m/%Y'), '%Y-%m-%d');
```

Comment: but please can you tell me how to convert the date on the go.

Comment: When you use it in your PHP scripts, convert it to the format you need it. Find out how to use php DateTime object

Comment: thanks bro... youve really help to resolve the issue, i appreciate